# How to subscribe the address logs in solana by using python?

Tags: python, solana

I want to subscribe the logs of my address in solana by using python

Answer (score 0):

[solana-py](https://michaelhly.github.io/solana-py/) has support for async websocket clients and log subscriptions. Also supports many other ***client*** side capabilities.

Writing programs, or smart contracts, are not possible in python at this time. For those you'd use Rust or rust-macro driven Anchor.

Comment: I've used this code which is mentioned in solana.py official docs

Comment: import asyncio
from asyncstdlib import enumerate
from solana.rpc.websocket_api import connect

async def main():
    async with connect("wss://api.devnet.solana.com") as websocket:
        await websocket.logs_subscribe()
        first_resp = await websocket.recv()
        subscription_id = first_resp.result
        next_resp = await websocket.recv()
        print(next_resp)
        

    
asyncio.run(main())

Comment: but when I use account_subscribe and pass my address to get real time logs it gives me the logs of the transaction that I perfrom after the subscription and after giving thev logs it's automatically unsubscribed